# Line of code ignored

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to clean my code to make it run under 'sections'.
There's one called `intro()`, another one called `second()` and so on..

The **issue** comes when I **switch** from the first section of **code** (`intro()`) to the **next** one (`second()`) which **should run a cleaning code first, but doesn't really!**

The `code` basically writes text on a `list` which should look like a chat, so the `intro()` is the first part of text then it should clear the chat and start writing other text inside `second()`.

This is my code, take a look:

```
int counter;
boolean introDone = false;



 //Intro
public void intro(){
        write(answers[counter], buttonText[counter]);
}

public void second(){
            write("So these are the rules:", R.string.go);
}

public void hello(View view){
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, Integer.toString(counter), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
    if(counter <= 2){
    intro();
    }else if(counter == 3){
        clear();
    }else if (counter > 2 && counter < 5) {
    second();}

    counter++;
}
```

}

This did the trick:

```
    //Intro
public void intro(){
        write(answers[counter], buttonText[counter]);

}

public void second(){
            write("So these are the rules:", R.string.go);
}

public void hello(View view) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, Integer.toString(counter), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
    if (counter <= 2) {
        intro();
    } else if(counter == 3) {
        introDone = true;
    }
    if (introDone) {
        clear();
        introDone = false;
    }
    if (counter > 2 && counter < 5) {
            second();
        }

    counter++;
}
```

}

Comment: Try if(introDone == true)..If that doesn't work then ti means that your IntroDone is false.

Comment: @Kristo1990 How changing `if(introDone)` to `if(introDone==true)` would that improve anything? Both codes will work same way, and your proposition only introduces possibility to make typo mistake like `if(introDone=true)` which is why `==true` should be avoided.

Comment: That seems to change nothing @Kristo1990

Comment: You need to assign a value in your if condition to your boolean in order to execute whatever is in your statement `{}` .

Comment: I know that for booleans you can leave the variable itself to automatically mean "If that's true then.."

Comment: You could try to put a print statement inside the outer if statement in second(), that way you know if that line is executed

Comment: it depends on how you have declared your boolean IntroDone if its `final` yes then its ok.

Comment: @FET To help you (and to make this question useful for future readers) we will need [minimal but fill code example which we could use to reproduce your problem](http://sscce.org). For now it looks like problem is that `introDone` is never true, which *may* mean that `if (counter <= 2)` condition is never false, or that you are resetting `introDone` to false somewhere else. To say more we will need to see more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that the boolean `introDone` variable is never true.  In your `intro()` method you have it wrapped with an if statement to check if the counter is 2 or less.  It is hard to tell without the full source, but I would guess that if you changed your code to this:

```
//Intro
public void intro(){

    //if (counter <= 2) {
      //  write(answers[counter], buttonText[counter]);
    //}else{
        introDone = true;
    //}

}

public void second(){
    if(introDone) {
        listViewMother.setAdapter(null); //THIS SHOULD CLEAN THE LIST, BUT INSTEAD WHEN I RUN THE CODE IT LOOKS LIKE IT JUST IGNORES IT
        if (counter > 2 && counter < 5) {
            write("So these are the rules:", R.string.go);
        }
    }
}

public void hello(View view){
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, Integer.toString(counter), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
    intro();
    second();
    counter++;
}
```

everything would work fine.

From there you could look at the logic around how you increment the counter variable and see if that was the issue.

This example will run call intro() and second() 10 times.

```
public void hello(View view){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, Integer.toString(counter), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        for (int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++) {
            intro();
            second();
        }

}
```

Comment: Hey James, I think you're right, you clarified me a concept of if/else statements so thank you. By the way I still can't really say if that worked as I need some text before which should be cleaned, but now I'm figuring out a way to achieve the final result :)

Comment: Good, please mark this as the correct answer if it worked.

Comment: You would use some kind of while or if statement to loop though calls to the intro() and second() methods and each loop would increment your counter variable.  That would solve your problem.

Comment: Looks like I have some problems on figuring that out.. any ideas? If so I will surely be happy to mark this answer as the correct one!

Comment: I'd appreciate a line of code if you so can, that would help as I'm a beginner :/

Comment: Hey, edited my code, now It's all good, it clears.. but when I start the second() method, the text I cleared comes back plus the second text gets added :/

Answer (score 0):

How is the variable *counter* and the variable *introDone* initialized?

I assume that the variable *counter* have the value 0 at the start of the program, and the variable *introDone* is false. If that is the case, then the code into *second* section isn't executed. Example:

```
public void hello(View view){
    // --> here, counter=0 and introDone=false
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, Integer.toString(counter), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
    intro(); // --> counter is still 0, so the variable introDone is still false
    second(); // --> because introDone=false then the code is not executed
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Try to see the updated question, I've added the initialazing stuff, oh and by the way it works at first click